# Guy of below average intelligence becomes super smart

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a movie I watched nearly fifteen years ago.

The climax of the movie is that this guy, now super intelligent, tries to merge with the cyber space. He keeps on trying different portals to find the right one. The scientist who made him smart tries to reason with him but he ignores him and banishes him from the cyber world. The scientist as a last resort sets up dynamites inside the lab to stop him but just as the bombs go off, he gets access into the cyberspace.

He states his first crime or act as a cybernetic being would be to call all the telephones in the world.

Just as the film is about to end and the scientist hugs his family, the telephone rings.

Comment: Better story in the genre "Guy of below average intelligence becomes super smart" is Flowers for Algernon, or in movie form Charly.

Answer (score 26):

It is [The Lawnmower Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lawnmower_Man_(film)) from 1992.

To confirm your final point: it ends with (spoilers)

> all the telephones in the world ringing, to show that The Lawnmower Man is still alive, in cyberspace.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely correct. [The CGI on the scene the asker mentions is awful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBeReLZ9TQg).

Comment: And if you liked that, the recent release _Lucy_ is quite a good watch.

Comment: @CrowTRobot Awful? As a teenager back in 1992, it was pretty awesome.

Comment: Also, the SNES game was pretty cool at the time.

Comment: Come on @CrowTRobot, surely you can think of a more creative riff than "awful"!